# Heat loss due to thermal penetration

Tags: thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I am doing an experiment on a regenerator (Period 120 s). I found the thermal penetration depth through the insulation as 13 mm. I'm not sure how to estimate this heat loss?. I tried to estimate by calculating the volume of that portion, then mass and finally Q. it gives the wrong answer. Somebody, please help me to estimate heat loss due to thermal penetration?